# Evaluate $\int_{[0,6]} \sin \frac{\lfloor x \rfloor \pi}{4} d\lambda$ / Notation check

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Given a measure space $(S, \Sigma, \mu) = ([0,6], \mathscr B([0,6]), \lambda)$,

evaluate $$\int_{[0,6]} \sin \frac{\lfloor x \rfloor \pi}{4} \lambda(dx)$$

---

$$\int_{[0,6]} \sin \frac{\lfloor x \rfloor \pi}{4} \lambda(dx)$$

$$ = \int_{[0,6]} \sin \frac{\lfloor x \rfloor \pi}{4} dx$$

$$= \int_{[0,1)} \sin \frac{\lfloor x \rfloor \pi}{4} dx + \int_{[1,2)} \sin \frac{\lfloor x \rfloor \pi}{4} dx + \int_{[2,3)} \sin \frac{\lfloor x \rfloor \pi}{4} dx$$

$$+ \int_{[3,4)} \sin \frac{\lfloor x \rfloor \pi}{4} dx + \int_{[4,5)} \sin \frac{\lfloor x \rfloor \pi}{4} dx + \int_{[5,6)} \sin \frac{\lfloor x \rfloor \pi}{4} dx$$

$$+ \underbrace{\int_{\{6\}} \sin \frac{\lfloor x \rfloor \pi}{4} dx}_{0}$$

$$= \int_{[0,1)} 0 dx + \int_{[1,2)} \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} dx + \int_{[2,3)} 1 dx$$

$$+ \int_{[3,4)} \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} dx + \int_{[4,5)} 0 dx + \int_{[5,6)} -\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} dx$$

$$= \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} + 1 $$

$$+ \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} +  -\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} $$

$$= \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} + 1 $$

Is that right? Value, notation, steps and all?

Comment: Did you mean $dx$ or $d\lambda$?

Comment: @IanMiller $\lambda(dx) = dx$ myb? There's no differential stated. It's kind of weird

Comment: I'm rusty on the techniques you've flagged so I'm not remembering the notation correctly. I looked it as a normal integral.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks correct to me, assuming $x$ and $\lambda$ are the same thing. [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%5BSin%5BFloor%5Bx%5D*Pi%2F4%5D%2C%20%7Bx%2C%200%2C%206%7D%5D) also agrees with you.

Comment: Thanks Ian Miller. Oh yeah got that computationally. Just wondering about the notations, steps, etc if I missed anything. Re notation, there's no differential stated in the problem, but this is supposed to be concerning Lebesgue measure. Is there then supposed to be $\lambda(dx) = dx$ at the end?

Comment: Sorry, I can't recall the notation well enough to comment if you setting out if right.